# Run two functions with Ajax calls sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two functions which has `ajax calls` inside them.

```
function a(){
    ajaxCall_A();
}
function b(){
    ajaxCall_B();
}
```

And I have another function which calls these two functions in the order of `a` then `b`.

```
function c(){
    a();
    b();
    // expectation : function 'b' will get executed only after function 'a' finished it's execution  
}
```

I'm not sure whether they are working as I expected or not. Some time it will do but some times it is not. I assume it's because the ajax calls , which are asynchronous , inside them.

How can I run the two functions in function 'c' to achieve the expectation.

**NOTE :**  Functions are like below

```
function a(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "url_a",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",               
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){             

        },
        error:function(){             

        }   
    });   
}

function b(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "url_b",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",               
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){             

        },
        error:function(){             

        }   
    });   
}
```

Comment: Your last revision makes no sense.  `ajaxCall_A` is not a function call.  It doesn't actually do anything.  You need `()` after it to make it a function call as in `ajaxCall_A()` or you need to show us the ACTUAL ajax code.

Comment: If you want more detailed help, then stop showing only pseudo-code and show us the actual Ajax code.

Comment: @jfriend00 edited. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: It's better if the people who downvote can give a reason for that. Will help to improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the ajax calls are asynchronous, you will need to manually sequence the ajax calls if you want the second one not to start until the first one is done.

Promises are uniquely suited for serializing asynchronous operations and they can make it quite simple.  Fortunately, jQuery has promises built in and every Ajax operation already returns a promise that can be used for this:

```
$.ajax(...).then(function(result1) {
    // make 2nd ajax call when the first has completed
    return $.ajax(...);
}).then(function(result2) {
    // success of both ajax calls here
}, function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Or, if you make `a()` and `b()` both return the jQuery ajax promises from their ajax calls, then you can just do this:

```
a().then(b);
```

And, `c()` could just be:

```
function c() {
    return a().then(b);
}
```

So, if you want to make a function call to contain both these Ajax calls without `a()` and `b()`, you should have it return a promise:

```
function c() {
    return $.ajax(...).then(function(result1) {
        // make 2nd ajax call when the first has completed
        return $.ajax(...);
    })
}
```

And, you can then call `c()` like this:

```
c().then(function(result) {
    // success here
}, function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

---

Here's an example of a function that returns an Ajax promise:

```
function test() {
    return $.ajax("http://www.test.com/api/test");
}
```

---

Now, that you've added your actual ajax code, you can just add a return:

```
function a(){ 
    return $.ajax({
        url: "url_a",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",               
        cache: false
    });   
}

function b(){ 
    return $.ajax({
        url: "url_b",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",               
        cache: false
    });   
}

function c() {
    return a().then(b);
}
```

Comment: @prime - it is not clear what your update changes.  See my comments to  below your question.

Comment: please refer the question. I just updated and added what the functions actually look like. I hope that's okay.

So is it okay to add the `return` before the ajax call ?

Comment: @prime - yes, you can add a `return`.  See what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: so can it be like `return a().then(b).then(d); if I have multiple functions`

Comment: @prime - yes.  Just make sure that all functions containing async operations return a promise that is tied to the async operation and you can chain as many as you want like this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `ajaxCall_A()` and `ajaxCall_B()` return promises, and add `return`s to `a()` and `b()`.

```
function a(){
    return ajaxCall_A();
}
function b(){
    return ajaxCall_B();
}
```

Then, `a()` and `b()` will execute sequentially as follows :

```
function c() {
    a().then(b);
}
```

You should also add a `return` to `c()` so it returns a promise to its caller.

```
function c() {
    return a().then(b);
}
```

Comment: `Make sure that ajaxCall_A() and ajaxCall_B() return promises` how can I do this ?

Comment: In both functions, `return $.ajax({...});`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use jQuery.when() & done() with Deferred:

```
    function a() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({
        url: "url_a",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",               
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){             
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        error:function(){             
           deferred.resolve("Error from a()");
       }   
      });  
      return deferred.promise();
    }
    function b() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({
        url: "url_b",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",               
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){             
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        error:function(){             
           deferred.resolve("Error from b()");
       }   
      }); 

        return deferred.promise();
    }

    function c()
    {
        $.when(
            a(),
            b()
       )
      .done(function ( v1, v2 ){
      //Do your work - v1 and v2 are resolved value from a() and b() 
      });       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow `a` function to accept a callback param to be executed when done, and send `b` function as a callback:

```
function c(){
  a(b); 
}

function a(callback){ 
  $.ajax({
    url: "url_a",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "html",               
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){             
      callback() // Note here call the next function
    },
    error:function(){             

    }   
  });   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to synchronize both of them using a semaphore

```
function c(){
    $semaphore=true;
    a();
    while($semaphore ) { 
         setTimeout("checksemaphore()", 500);
    } 
    b();
    // expectation : function 'b' will get executed only after function 'a' finished it's execution  
}


inside the ajax call to a
add a complete: 

complete : function(result) { 
            $waitsemaphore= 0 ; },
error: function(result) {alert("AJAX completed w/error");alert(result);},
```

Comment: Why in the world would you poll for completion when you can just hook directly into the completion event itself or the promise notification?  There is no need for `setTimeout()` polling here at all.