# how to execute request on javascript that returns value then use this value as parameter for post request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a two request first one return a value

> first request

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/controller/action',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {

            result = data.result;


            const add_some_data_at_result = "somdata";}] };

            var obj = JSON.parse(request);
            obj['value'][0].value = editedre; },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);

        }
    })
```

I want to make second request wait until the first one complete to use its value as a parameter for the second on

> second request

```
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/controller/secondAction',
                data: { fits: JSON.stringify(obj) },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data.status.includes("Error")) {
                        console.log(data.status);

                        alert('done!');
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

any help?

Comment: Have a look at this question, [Run Ajax Sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332491/run-two-functions-with-ajax-calls-sequentially#33332528)

Comment: Use promises (instead of `success` and `error` callbacks) and chain them using `then`

Comment: thank u both very much .. 
it's now working sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/controller/action',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {

        result = data.result;


        const add_some_data_at_result = "somdata";}] };

        var obj = JSON.parse(request);
        obj['value'][0].value = editedre; },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);

    }
})
  }).then(
  function (result1) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/controller/secondAction',
            data: { fits: JSON.stringify(obj) },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.status.includes("Error")) {
                    console.log(data.status);

                    alert('done!');
                    
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
     });
    })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).